# LCM program in C++

Tags: c++, lcm

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter two numbers (remember to put 
a space between them):\n";

    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    const int num_limit = num1 * num2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_limit; i++)
    {
        int product = num1 * i;
        int product2 = num2 * i;

        // test for when multiples are equal
        if (product == product2)
        {
        cout << "The LCM of " << num1 << " and " << 
num2 << " is: "; 
        }

     }
}
```

I'm trying to get the LCM from two integers which the user enters. The if statement within the for loop isn't doing what I intended it to do, as nothing prints when product and product2 are equal. What is the solution to this little problem?

Comment: *i* is same in both multiplications, so products are equal when *num1 == num2*...

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-lcm-of-two-numbers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter two numbers (remember to put a space between them):\n";

    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    int num_limit = num1 * num2,LCM;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_limit; i++)
    {
        LCM = num1 * i;

        // test for when multiples are equal
        if (LCM%num2==0) break;
    }
    cout << "The LCM of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is: " << LCM;
    _getch();// replace with getch(); if didn't work
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. Thank you :) Where does LCM come from? Is this a 'special' variable, as I don't see it declared anywhere?

Comment: You're welcome. I declared it where you declared num_limit variable (at the end of the line)...

Answer (score 1):

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd(b,a%b);  
}

int lcm(int a,int b)
{
    //Efficient Solution
    // a*b=gcd(a,b)*lcm(a,b)

    return (a*b)/gcd(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<lcm(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
15 12
60
```

Comment: This is the correct solution based on the Euclidean algorithm. If anyone is in doubt, try running this and the accepted answer on a couple of 6-digit numbers.